# How to prevent load each row (image) in recycleview

Tags: android, android-fragments, scroll, android-recyclerview, picasso

I have to show an image into imageview in my layout for recycleview' s row.
RecycleView use ViewHolder pattern so my code is in custom ViewHolder.

To load the images I need to use an AsynkTask that return a File in onPostExecute(). In this onPostExecute() I setup imageView with Picasso.

I tried to obtain the same file without use AsynkTask. So I call directly Picaso.with()....

In this scenario, recycleview lag so much when scrolling, but i notified that Picasso cache all images.

The first scenario with AynkTask has more than one problem. Scrolling down and up for x times with 100 row make the queue of asynktask bigger. 
Now, if I open a fragment of drawer, queue of Asynkask continues to load and this selected fragment make its work so slowly.

how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

1. I would suggest you to checkout **Image Management Library by Facebook** that is [Fresco](http://frescolib.org/) that is pretty awesome and mature as compared to other Image Loading Library.
2. When image in a view goes out of screen it automatically recycles the bitmap, hence releasing the memory (Making scrolling smooth).
3. Fresco handles all the things caching of images with 3 Tier architecture ( `BITMAP_MEMORY_CACHE`, `ENCODED_MEMORY_CACHE` and `DISK_CACHE`).
4. It also reduces OOM (Out Of Memory) issues.